# get today's date and time as string

Tags: java, calendar

I am new to Java and trying to use Calendar object to get date and time of now as a string. I am particularly stuck at object and object conversions.

Here is the format I need (as a string):
   2016-03-30T14:21:00Z

If I could just get the date and time format right, I could play around with the string but I am struggling with deprecated methods.

Thank you for replies

Comment: `System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()))`, if you have a particular date format you need you can use `SimpleDateFormat` to customise the format.  Alternatively, you can use Java 8's Time API which has a number of predefined formatters to handle those types of formats, [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_DATE_TIME) comes to mind

Comment: *"I could play around with the string"* is a scary thought, better to use the Time API or Joda Time to manipulate the actual time value

Comment: @Ben77 Please search Stack Overflow before posting. The basic date-time questions have already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to start using Java 8's new Time API (or JodaTime if you can't use Java 8)

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
String isoFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(now.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
System.out.println(isoFormat);
```

outputs `2016-03-30T17:51:38.639Z` (when I tested it)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to stick to Java 7 :(

Comment: The use JodaTime which is very similar to Java 8's Time API

Answer (score 1):

Solved my question using this link:

http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/current-date-time-in-java/

Thanks for replies, I will also look into Java 8' time API